# NoClassDefFoundError while trying to sign an apk file using JarSigner.exe

Tags: java, android, apk, noclassdeffounderror, jarsigner

I try to sign an android application using the file JarSigner.exe (In windows).

What I did was creating a designated dir in which I placed the JarSigner.exe along with all the other files in JRE\bin.

Of course I also put there the keystore file.

I openned a cmd window (as an administrator) and changed dir to the designated dir I created.

There I gave the command:

```
jarsigner -keystore myKeystore myApp.apk myself
```

The result was as follows:

```
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/t
ools/JarSigner
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.tools.JarSigner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: sun.security.tools.JarSigner.  Program will exit.
```

Does someone know why does it happen, or how can I fix it?

Comment: you can verify if tools.jar is in the classpath ?

Comment: yes, it is in the same dir as the JarSigner.exe ...

Answer (score 0):

> What I did was creating a designated dir in which I placed the JarSigner.exe along with all the other files in JRE

That was your mistake. What you should have done was adjust the PATH to include the JDK bin directory, or provide the full path to jarsigner,exe when running it.

Answer (score 0):

you must be add tools.jar to your classpath you can look this link for more information

[how you can add JAR in to Classpath in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2012/10/5-ways-to-add-multiple-jar-to-classpath-java.html)